# Is params[:value] a model variable or can be local as well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi people i have a question regarding params[:value].

Must my model consist of the variable attribute called value only i can use this params[:value] in my controller ?

I'm trying to get data from my VIEW but the variable values will only be used for 1 of the function only. So i was thinking if there's an alternative way to do.

In my view [this question is related to the 2nd radio_button = Number Of ATGC specified]:

```
<%= form_for (@generator ) do |f| %>
  <% if @generator.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@generator.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this generator from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @generator.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <label>Primer Length</label><br>
       <%= f.number_field :primer_length , min: 3 %>
  </div>

    <label>Selection :</label><br>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><label>Randomly</label>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:choice, 'Randomly', true )%></th>

        <th><label>Number of ATGC specified</label>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:choice,'No_of_ATGC')%> </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><label>Number of A :</label>
            <%= number_field_tag 'No_of_A'%><br>
            <label>Number of T :</label>
            <%= number_field_tag 'No_of_T'%><br>
            <label>Number of G :</label>
            <%= number_field_tag 'No_of_G'%><br>
            <label>Number of C :</label>
            <%= number_field_tag 'No_of_C'%><br></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>    

<%= button_to('Generate',generate_option_generator_path(@generator))%>
<% end %>
```

In GeneratorController

```
class GeneratorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_generator, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  after_action :generate_option, only: [:create, :update]
  # GET /generators
  # GET /generators.json
  def index
    @generators = Generator.all
  end

  # GET /generators/1
  # GET /generators/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /generators/new
  def new
    @generator = Generator.new
  end

  # GET /generators/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /generators
  # POST /generators.json
  def create    
    @generator = Generator.new(generator_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.save
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @generator }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1
  # PATCH/PUT /generators/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @generator.update(generator_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @generator, notice: 'Generator was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        #random_generate
        #@generator.save!
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @generator.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /generators/1
  # DELETE /generators/1.json
  def destroy
    @generator.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to generators_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def generate_option
    @generator.choice = params[:choice]
    if params[:choice] == 'Randomly'
        random_generate
    elsif params[:choice] == 'No_of_ATGC'

    end
    @generator.save!
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_generator
      @generator = Generator.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def generator_params
      params.require(:generator).permit(:primer_length, :choice, :random_primer_generated)
    end
end
```

In ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception 
  def random_generate
     length = @generator.primer_length
        chars = 'ATGC'
        seq = ''
        length.times { seq << chars[rand(chars.size)] }
       @generator.random_primer_generated = seq
  end

  def no_ATGC

    counts = {'a'=>no_of_a,'t'=>no_of_a,'g'=>no_of_a,'c'=>no_of_a}
    @generator.random_primer_generated = Bio::Sequence::NA.randomize(counts)

  end

end
```

Basically that's what i need to do. I need to know how many A's T's G's and C's in order to generate something out for user. Also i'm not sure if the gem Bioruby is accessible in Rails ~ I don't have to worry much in RUby but Rails architecture is alittle hard. I've defined the gem Bioruby in my gemfile. Hope it works.

Comment: can you please put here some of your code as an example?

Comment: I've updated the content. Hi Muntasim :P i've decided not to use that JQuery but table view first. Will do enhancement later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model is concerned if you try to create/update the model item with the params. You can pass anything as params to controller, but if you create/update the model item, the parameters must be in the model.

Comment: OK noted... in my case i need the variable to be in my model because i need to create. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

params contains information received from submitted form.  So, it really depends on whether you had a field (edit box, selection box, etc) with name "value" in your form or not.  Since, most of Rails forms are generated from Model, typically, it would mean that you had an attribute "value" in your model.